# Eclipse shortcuts in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to set the shortcuts for Visual Studio to the shortcuts I'm used from eclipse?

I know I can go to the options and set every single shortcut manually. But I'm looking for a way to set them all at once. Some kind of key map import plus an eclipse key map file maybe!?

Comment: There is an add-in for the earlier versions of VS (2010, 2008, 2005) called "AsEclipse" that does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

To set up your keyboard short cuts in VS2013, Go to the dialog:  TOOLS->Options->Environment->Keyboard .

Once you have your environment the way you like it, export the setting in the following dialog:
TOOLS->Options->Environment->Import and Export Settings.

Once exported you can copy the file and import them to any other machine you may use.  This can also be used for saving a common settings file for your team in TFS (or any other revision control system you may be using).

Personally, I have not played with this feature so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Is there maybe a settings file available, that I could import to set all the eclipse keybindings? Something for VS2013 like "AsEclipse" would be also nice.

Comment: did somebody do this and uploaded the file somewhere?